# Заполнение таблицы при совпадении лицевого счета в двух файлах

Tags: python, excel

Есть *Excel* файл из более чем 10000 лицевых счетов.У каждого лицевого счета есть поле для заполнения показаний (пустые).

Есть второй Excel файл из примерно 3500 тысяч лицевых счетов (взяты из первого общего *Excel* файла), у которых заполненные показания.

Надо эти показания влить в общий *Excel* файл (10-тысячный). То есть надо, чтобы показания заполнились только у тех лицевых счетов, у которых есть показания.
Пример: Первый Excel файл(10 тысячный):[image: 10-тысячный с пустыми показаниями]

Второй Excel файл(около 3-тысяч) с заполненными показаниями [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *VBA* или формульное решение в *Excel* не рассматриваете?

Comment: Все варианты рассматриваю

Comment: Почему показания ЛС №9 не попали в первый файл?

Comment: Они есть. В Первом файле 10 тысяч номеров. Во втором 3 тысячи, но не по порядку. Во втором только счета с показаниями. То есть только те у кого есть показания.

Comment: ЛС №9 на Вашем примере в первом файле не отображен, отсюда и вопрос. Примеры нужно точнее составлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(K2;[вторая_книга.xlsx]sheet1!$A$1:$C$3000;3;);)
```

Будут подтянуты показания по лицевым счетам. Если ЛС не найден - ноль.

Если нули мешают:

`Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Для_листа`, снять галку "*показывать нулевые значения*"

Comment: их не ровно 3000, а примерно столько.

Comment: Вместо 3000 - любое число, не меньше номера последней строки с даными.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# чтение Excel файлов в pandas.DataFrame's
df1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Temp\1.xlsx", index_col="лиц.счет")
df2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Temp\2.xlsx", index_col="лиц. счет")[["показания"]]

# заполнение столбца "показания"
df1["показания"] = df1["показания"].combine_first(df2["показания"])

# запись результата в Excel файл
df1.reset_index().to_excel(r"c:/temp/result.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Выходит ошибка: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects